# Criar um Android App Bundle com Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin-forms, apk, bundle, google-play

Quando tento publicar publicar um app Xamarin.Android no console do desenvolvedor Android recebo a seguinte mensagem de aviso que não me deixa publicar o app:

[image: Mensagem de Aviso APK não otimizado]

Neste caso como eu poderia criar um APK otimizado, ou seja, como poderia criar um Android App Bundle de um app desenvolvido em Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo problema hoje e infelizmente não achei uma solução para este aviso. Alterei os ABIS suportados, tentei criar um package para cada ABI e subir separadamente, mas o aviso continuou em todos os casos.

Conforme a seguinte postagem no forum do xamarin https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138216/android-app-bundle-dynamic-delivery, foi comentado que a solução estava no github do xamarin forms, porém não achei nada referente a isto.

No final das contas isto é apenas um aviso e pode ser ignorado. O problema é que nem todos os itens obrigatórios estão preenchidos. Verifica do lado esquerdo quais itens não estão com o check verde. No meu caso era o App Content

[image: App Content não preenchido]

Após preencher os dados e o check ficar verde vai conseguir fazer a publicação da versão normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Nas propriedades do projecto Android -> Avançadas -> em Supported ABIS, seleccionar
armeabi e armeabi-v7a

Comment: Bruno Caceiro essas opções que você mencionou são do Android Studio ou do Xamarin Forms? Porque no meu caso eu estou desenvolvendo usando Xamarin Forms..

Comment: São no Visual Studio, tanto para Mac como para Windows, e sim, usando XamarinForms

Answer (score 0):

Passos para gerar o arquivo .aab no Visual Studio 2019 para desenvolvimento com Xamarin.Forms:

1. Clique com o botão direito em seu projeto e selecione Propriedades.
2. Navegue até as opções do Android.
3. Altere sua configuração para Release.
4. Altere o formato do pacote Android para bundle.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de concluir essas etapas, você pode gerar um pacote de aplicativos clicando com o botão direito do mouse em seu projeto e selecionando Arquivar (Archive) para gerar o arquivo bundle (.aab)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho extraído da fonte:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/

Comment: A pessoa que negativou a minha resposta acima, provavelmente foi uma das que deram a resposta errada. Não existe como criar arquivo .aab apenas mudando o tipo de suporte ao processador. Além do mais, já é definição da própria Google Play que APKs só serão aceitos até agosto de 2021. Após essa data deve-se fazer o procedimento que eu citei acima para criação correta do arquivo para upload no Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um jeito fácil para resolver isto.

- No projeto do Android, clique com o botão direito e selecione a opção: "Descarregar Projeto";
- Em seguida, o Visual studio vai abrir o arquivo .csproj;
- Pesquise pela palavra: "AndroidPackageFormat"... Quando você localizar, você troca a opção **apk** por **aab**, ficando desta forma:

```html
<AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
```

Feito isto, salve o arquivo e clique novamente com o botão direito no projeto do android, e selecione a opção "Recarregar Projeto"... Pronto!

Agora você pode arquivar novamente o projeto e o arquivo .aab será gerado.